# Rails: Retrieving JPG instead of HEIC from Cloudinary

Tags: cloudinary, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently working on a Rails 6 application using ActiveStorage where I'm trying to render images as jpg. I'm using [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations) to render the images. I'm trying to support `.HEIC` images in my web app. A user can upload `HEIC` images to Cloudinary but I would like for my application to render the image as `jpg`

When I render the image I see that the browser is rendering the `HEIC` image which is not supported by browsers.
[image]

ActiveStorage uploads the image to the cloud:

```
Redirected to http://res.cloudinary.com/XXXXXXXXX/image/upload/xxxxxxxxxxxq3r4.HEIC
Completed 302 Found in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 16.1ms | Allocations: 2588)
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [ac0d5880-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx]   Cloudinary Storage (338.6ms) Downloaded file from key: kjpith3bxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [ac0d5880-a243-4fef-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] Skipping image analysis because ImageMagick doesn't support the file
```

However, I try to render the image from the views as `jpg` using the following.

```
<%= cl_image_tag(url_for(post.image), :format => :jpg , class: "card-home__img") %>
```

But the image is still calling the `HEIC` image format from this url:

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/artsyspace/image/upload/v1584732132/wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og.heic
```

Instead of calling the `jpg`

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/artsyspace/image/upload/v1584732132/wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og.jpg
```

How can I configure Cloudinary and ActiveStorage to render images or convert images to jpg?

Comment: Please do not post images of error messages. Please copy and paste as text. You can configure ImageMagick to use the libheif delegate and then use convert to read the heif image and output as jpg.

Comment: @fmw42 could you provide some direction on how to go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry, I only know the command line commands. `convert https://res.cloudinary.com/artsyspace/image/upload/v1584732132/wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og.heic result.jpg`. But you need to compile imagemagick with libheif to be able to read HEIC images. See https://github.com/strukturag/libheif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails 6, `.key` will return the Cloudfare's image ID.

```
<%= cl_image_tag(post.image.key, :format => :jpg , class: "card-home__img") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly, [the documentation in one place](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/rails_image_manipulation#converting_to_another_image_format) says the argument is `fetch_format`, while [another](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#fetch_format) shows an example using `format`.

Worst case, if you're having trouble with the `cl_image_tag` helper, you can write your own to construct the URL with a `.png` extension.

https://res.cloudinary.com/artsyspace/image/upload/v1584732132/wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og.jpg

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending the full url to the `cl_image_tag` method.

The `cl_image_tag` needs just the public id to generate the url. 
So the call should be:

```
<%= cl_image_tag("wbnknx9ighl6p4ok072u7kd8r5og", :format => :png , class: "card-home__img") %>
```

Of course, make sure to change the hardcoded public id above to the variable holding the public id.

You can get the public id of the resource in the response of the upload.

And one note on the difference between Cloudinary's `format` and `fetch_format`:

`format` would change the extension of the resource i.e

```
Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url('sample', :format => "png")
```

will produce https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.png

while using `fetch_foramt` will change the format using the relevant flag, i.e

```
Cloudinary::Utils.cloudinary_url('sample', :fetch_format => "png")
```

which will produce https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/f_png/sample

In this specific case, both would produce the same `png` image, but using `fetch_format` would allow using one of Cloudinary's best features which is optimizing the image automatically using `:fetch_format => "auto"`: https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/f_auto/sample